# balanced bracket C++ not working, what am i doing wrong

Tags: c++, string, brackets

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    int i, j=0, perlen, countcp=0, countsp=0, countrp=0, countcl=0, countsl=0, countrl=0;
    string str, str1;
    cout<<"Please enter string"<<endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    perlen=(str.length())/2;
    for(i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='{')
            countcp++;  
        if(str[i]=='[')
            countsp++;
        if(str[i]=='(')
            countrp++;
        if(str[i]=='}')
            countcl++;
        if(str[i]==']')
            countsl++;
        if(str[i]==')')
            countrl++;
    }
    str1=str;

    if(countcp==countcl and countsp==countsl and countrp==countrl)
    {
        cout<<"equal"<<endl;
        int countwhile=0, j=0;
        while(!str.length()==0)
        {
            if(str[j]=='{' and str[j+1]=='}')
            {
                str.erase(i, 2);
                countwhile++;
            }
            else if(str[j]=='(' and str[j+1]==')')
            {
                str.erase(i, 2);
                countwhile++;
            }
            else if(str[j]=='[' and str[j+1]==']')
            {
                str.erase(i, 2);
                countwhile++;
            }
            if(countwhile>perlen)
            {
                countwhile=1;
                cout<<"reached break"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if(countwhile==1)
        {
            cout<<"Balanced string "<<str1<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to balance brackets. input will include curly, round and square brackets. i am trying to find what i did wrong in this code. i am new to c++ and i am trying to learn.

explanation

countcp for **c**urly o**p**en brackets
countsp for **s**quare **o**pen brackets
countrp for round open brackets
countcl for curly close or last bracket open brackets
countsl for square close brackets
countrl for round close brackets
eg. input {()}
    output balanced
    input {(}{)}
    output not balanced
 it works till line 30 and prints equal after that it gives error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Explain the failing case

Comment: You should inspect your code using the debugger and step through your code line by line. That's probably more efficient than asking an unclear question here.

Comment: you are checking only for `str[j]` and `str[j+1]`. I suggest better use stack for this que.

Comment: Your while condition never becoming zero.

Comment: hint: This task is to train use of stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. Missing return type in `main`. Use:

   ```
   int main() ...
   ```
2. Accessing array out of bounds. You have:

   ```
   while ( !str.length() == 0 )
   ```

   That is not adequate. You also need to make sure that you don't access `str` out of bounds. Hence, change that to:

   ```
   while ( !str.length() == 0 && j+1 < str.length() )
   ```

   or, better,

   ```
   while ( !str.empty() && j+1 < str.length() )
   ```

   Use of `j+1` is necessary since you are accessing `str[j+1]` in the loop.
3. Erasing the wrong elements from the string. Instead of

   ```
   str.erase(i, 2);
   //        ^^
   ```

   use

   ```
   str.erase(j, 2);
   //        ^^
   ```
4. You are not updating the value of `j` properly. Say `str` is equal to `"{()}". When`j`is equal to`1`, you are trying to remove`()`from the string. After that,`str`is equal to`"{}". In order to be able process that, you need to set the value of `j` to `0`. The logic needs to be:

   Increment `j` when there is no match.
   Decrement `j` when there is a match and the matching characters are removed.

**Suggestion for improvement**

Use an unsigned type for `i` and `j` to avoid compiler warnings.

You can use:

```
std::string::size_type i = 0;
std::string::size_type j = 0;
```

**Updated version of the `while` loop with the above fixes**

I have also added additional `cout` lines to help diagnose logic errors.

```
  int countwhile=0;
  std::string::size_type j=0;
  while(!str.length()==0 && j+1 < str.length())
  {
     if(str[j]=='{' and str[j+1]=='}')
     {
        cout<<"erasing {}"<<endl;
        str.erase(j, 2);
        cout << str << endl;
        countwhile++;
        --j;
     }
     else if(str[j]=='(' and str[j+1]==')')
     {
        cout<<"erasing ()"<<endl;
        str.erase(j, 2);
        cout << str << endl;
        countwhile++;
        --j;
     }
     else if(str[j]=='[' and str[j+1]==']')
     {
        cout<<"erasing []"<<endl;
        str.erase(j, 2);
        cout << str << endl;
        countwhile++;
        --j;
     }
     else
     {
        j++;
     }
     if(countwhile>perlen)
     {
        countwhile=1;
        cout<<"reached break"<<endl;
        break;
     }
  }
```

In order to be able process input like `"{[}{]}"` correctly, you have to restructure the code a bit. This does not seem like the right place to suggest an elaborate refactoring of your code to be able to handle such input.

Comment: Thank-you very much now it works. i am still testing it for larger strings.

Comment: after all the edits it works for ({}).  but doesnt work for ({({}})).

Comment: @Dementor, you will need to use a different strategy and algorithm for dealing with such inputs. You'll have to spend some time working through such input in pencil and paper before working on updating the program.

Comment: @R Sahu, i am matching adjacent brackets they why is it failing

Comment: @Dementor, no you are not. Look carefully.

Comment: @Dementor, My suggestion: Look for the closing characters. If you find one such character, check the value of the previous character. If that is not a matching character, then there is a problem. Otherwise, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
str.erase(i, 2);
```

seems wrong as `i` is not part of the loop. `i` is equal `str.length();` which causes the erase to fail.

Did you mean

```
str.erase(j, 2);
```

Comment: yes, i mean j thnx for help but now i am getting an error  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: I think you need to set `j` back to zero after each erase. Or perhaps set it to `-1` as you have a `j++` later. The idea must be to start all over whenever you erased a matching pair.

Comment: yes tht was the issue i forgot to make j zero. thnx now it is working

Answer (score 0):

so thw while should be like this

```
while(!str.length()==0 and j+1 < str.length())
            {
                     if(str[j]=='{' and str[j+1]=='}')
                    {
                        str.erase(j, 2);
                        countwhile++;
                        j--;
                    }
                else if(str[j]=='(' and str[j+1]==')')
                    {
                        str.erase(j, 2);
                        countwhile++;
                        j--;
                    }
                else if(str[j]=='[' and str[j+1]==']')
                    {
                        str.erase(j, 2);
                        countwhile++;
                        j--;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                if(countwhile>perlen)
                    {
                        countwhile=1;
                        cout<<"reached break"<<endl;
                    }
                if(countwhile==1)
                    {
                        cout<<"Balanced string "<<str1<<endl;
                        break;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        cout<<"not Balanced "<<str1<<endl;
                        break;
                    }
            }
```